# bash script for kill PID from pgrep grunt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm an allstar noob to bash scripting. My script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

pgrep grunt > target.txt  
for i in target.txt  
   do kill $i
   echo "killed $i"  
done
```

Now, obviously it did not worked and i don't know how to make it work.
I want this script to `echo` the output from `pgrep grunt` to the file **target.txt** and from there to read the `PID` and kill those processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i; do 
   kill $i
   echo "killed $i"
done< <(pgrep grunt)
```

*An external file is not needed*.

But, are you aware of `pkill` existence ?

```
 pkill grunt
```

> pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other
>   attributes

Answer (score 0):

Read file using bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do 
    kill $line
    echo "killed $line"
done < target.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for pid in $(grep grunt) ; do
    kill ${pid} && echo "killed ${pid}"
done
```